# Scala's extension of the curiosly recurring generic pattern

Tags: design-patterns, scala, generics, self-type

While asking/editing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276706/what-do-user-defined-value-classes-look-like-from-java), I noticed that you can do this to achieve with full static safety the point of the original "curiously recurring template/generic pattern":

```
trait MyTrait[This <: MyTrait[This]] { this: This =>
  def myBinOp(other: This): This
}
```

This seems to let you remove one of the major needs for implicit conversions and Scala's ad-hoc type-class pattern, because the self-type removes the ability to declare

```
class A extends MyTrait[Nothing]
```

and similar things, which is the only problem I know of with the original pattern.  Is there something I've missed?  Why hasn't everyone (in Scala) started using this?

Comment: But does it avoid weird inferences? It certainly doesn't seem to avoid the ability of returning an ancestor type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't actually work, as Daniel C. Sobral's comment pointed out.  I don't know why I missed this, because it seems so obvious in hindsight:

```
class A extends MyTrait[A] {...} // Linearization:  A, MyTrait[A], AnyRef, Any
class B extends A {...} // Linearization:  B, A, MyTrait[A], AnyRef, Any
```

The huge problem with this is that `B`'s `myBinOp` returns `A` instead of `B`.

Comment: But the `this: This =>` annotation still prevents some basic errors. I've been using it for some time, although I hadn't realized this problem.

Comment: The real problem is that you can't do this:

`class B extends A with MyTrait[B]`

type erasure prohibit it